# Spartacus Catalog Sync

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

while doing catalog sync from electronics catalog to spa catalog for stage version getting below error this happened OOB ...class incompatibility is there.. any suggestions?

INFO  [SyncWorker<000000RT 1 of 1>] [AbstractItemCopyContext] type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.contents.components.CMSFlexComponent -> class de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.jalo.components.JspIncludeComponent is not allowed since types are not compatible

This causing job failure. It is trying to sync two not compatible components.

Comment: JspIncludeComponent usage is replaced with CMSFlexComponent in spartacus. As I remember from when we were syncing at the start of our project, there should be remove impexes for JspInclude components in initialdata -> coredata or sampledata. You can safely just remove Jsp components from electronics catalog to prevent syncing.

Comment: Okay I can see remove impexes in cleaning.impex of spartacus add on [partacussampledataaddon\import\contentCatalogs\bhContentCatalog\cleaning.impex], but not in electronics content catalog.
Which means I can remove these JspIncludeComponent from electronics content catalog.   As I understood spa content catalog's source is Electronics content catalog then how cmsflexcomponent will be sourced as I can not see Cmsflexcomponent in electronics content . It is only in SPA content catalog.

OR CmsFlexComponent will be independent of electronics content catalog and just part of SPA content catalog

Comment: SPA uses electronics content catalog as it's template in impexes, with changes to fit spartacus. It's almost identical to electronics site without spartacus. But they are two seperate catalogs. You'll be using the components of SPA Electronics catalog since you'll be using spartacus in your website. You have no need for the other electronics catalog anymore, you can even safely delete it.